# Why there is so high computational cost of multiplication in Microsoft Seal?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto, ring-lwe

I was doing some Microsoft Seal testing on my macbook pro (i7) and got following results

Coefficient mod $q = 100$ bits and Polynomial degree $n= 8192$

- Ciphertext-Plaintext multiplication takes 0.211 milliseconds
- Ciphertext-Ciphertext multiplication takes 24 milliseconds, when I pick 5 RNS moduli for coefficient mod.
- It takes 9 milliseconds when I pick 2 RNS moduli for coefficient mod.

I want to understand why Ciphertext-Ciphertext is so much more expensive than Ciphertext-Plaintext, I was expecting only 4-10 more expensive due to tensor multiplication?

Note above results are without relinearization.